# Error:HttpHostConnectionException

Tags: java, android, web-services, google-app-engine

i've made a web servide to join code deployed on google-app-engine with my android application.

whenever i try to do so i get the following error:
Error:HttpHostConnectionException:Connection to http://localhost:60569 refused
can somebody please tell the solution of it...
here is my android code:-

```
private void navigate() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
 {

     DefaultHttpClient hc=new DefaultHttpClient(); 
     ResponseHandler <String> res=new BasicResponseHandler();
     HttpPost postMethod=new HttpPost("http://localhost:60569/PendingRequest.jsp"); 
     List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("empId",empId));
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("empName",name));
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("empPhnNo",phoneNo));
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("empEmail",email));

     postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  
     String response=hc.execute(postMethod,res); 
     System.out.println("7");
     System.out.println(response);

     Intent intent=new Intent(this,RegisterEmployeeSecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

add this code in your manifest...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: +1: its sometimes so easy when you can read the message given by the error, right? :)

Comment: @jasmeet: localhost is always the device. To get to the localhost of the PC that runs the emulator, try this IP: `10.0.2.2`.

Comment: @jasmeet: please use @WarrenFaith so I got notified when you write a comment thats addressed to me... You are using localhost as url in your HttpPost. Change that to the IP `10.0.2.2`...